# dlv attach <pid> [binary location] gives access denied

Tags: debugging, go, delve

I am trying to attach delve golang debugger to my go program which is already running on my "Windows" 7 machine. when i say dlv attach  [binary location], it says "Could not attach to pid : Access is denied.

Could someone help me on this, i am running my CMD with Administrator privledge and the go program is running as SYSTEM.

Comment: Is it possible that something is locking the file, for example writing to the binary?

Comment: You mean binary permission? its writable.